# What does ピグ mean? (Not pig.)

Tags: meaning

I was reading http://helps.ameba.jp/faq/pigg/5301/post_362.html, and it said "ピグ", I can't for the life figure out for the life of me what it means (Unless it means pig, and contextually that makes no sense to me.)

Comment: http://sooda.jp/qa/407026

Comment: Hint:「自分そっくりなキャラクター」 ^^;

Comment: Well, the post says what it is - or are you asking where it comes from, in which case see snailboat's link.  At any rate, it seems they are well aware that it could be seen as "pig" in English ( http://vsmedia.info/2013/04/01/amebapig/ ｗｗｗ)

Comment: I've heard 「アメ～バ・ピグ♪」on TV commercials many times but I don't know what it is! ahaha

Comment: Look at the web address and see the word pigg!

Answer (score 2):

Normally a typical young Japanese netizen might tell you `ggrks` and I did that for you... but it showed no result, as I have expected.

Well, as its a popular Japanese Sim-like game, you can't really say that there's an etymology for this probably. If you still believe so, how would you explain all those spells in Dragon Quest like リレミト? :)

And for your information, there is a Japanese word for 'pig' which is 豚, more commonly written as ブタ, and if you insist to use an English-derived version, then it's ピッグ (the infamous Zombie Pigman was written as ゾンビピッグマン in the Japanese Minecraft Wiki) , not ピグ.